# Vue3: How to prevent further input when value meets a certain condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm primarily a React developer but I'm dipping my toes back into Vue again.

I'm making an app which allows you to convert your running pace between minutes per km and minutes per mile. The minute and second values for each unit are set in a parent component and passed down into child input components. I would like to prevent users from entering values higher than 59 into the number inputs but the `v-model` functionality continues to allow users to type beyond that.

I'm probably approaching this from a React mindset, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

#### `App.vue`

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <NumberInput
            :id="'kmMins'"
            :unit="'km'"
            v-model="kmMins"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import NumberInput from "./NumberInput.vue";
    export default {
        name: "App",
        data() {
            return {
                kmMins: 0,
            }
        },
        components: {
            NumberInput
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### `NumberInput.vue`

```html
<template>
    <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="00"
        :value="modelValue"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', sanitize($event))"
    />
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "NumberInput",
        props: ['id', 'unit', 'modelValue'],
        methods: {
            sanitize(e) {
                const { value } = e.target;
                if (!Number.isNaN(value) && value < 60) {
                    return value;
                }
                return this.modelValue;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does setting the `max="59"` attribute on the `input` not work? I've not done this in Vue before so maybe that's a dumb question.

Comment: @MattU No, that only works if you're using the arrow inputs sadly.

Answer (score 0):

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <NumberInput
            :id="'kmMins'"
            :unit="'km'"
            v-model="kmMins"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import NumberInput from "./NumberInput.vue";
    export default {
        name: "App",
        data() {
            return {
                kmMins: 0,
            }
        },
        components: {
            NumberInput
        },
        watch: {
            kmMins(newValue, oldValue){
                 if(newValue > 59){
                    this.kmMins = 59
                 }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Have you considered using watch? I haven't tested it but I think this will work. If it works you can deal with it for now.

Comment: I'm doing something with watch at the moment and having some success, but ideally I need it to be dynamic for four different inputs (kmMins, kmSecs, miMins, miSecs). I'd prefer not to set up four separate watches as I imagine that's quite heavy going.

Comment: You are right about this, but I would recommend using watch rather than solving this with the help of method. Because watch only when the relevant state changes. @ChrisWickham

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="00"
        v-model= "checkNumber"
    />
</template>

<script>
        export default {
        name: "NumberInput",
        props: ['id', 'unit', 'modelValue'],
        data(){
return{
    checkNumber : 0,
}
        },
        watch:{
            checkNumber(val){
                if(val<5){
                    $emit('update:modelValue', sanitize($event))
                }else{
                    console.log(">>> value greater then 5" , val)
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sanitize(e) {
                const { value } = e.target;
                if (!Number.isNaN(value) && value < 60) {
                    return value;
                }
                return this.modelValue;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

in the above code i have used watch which is like `useEffect` in react this will watch the variable change in every change like `onChange` function in react.
And if the data if greater then 5 it will send error . else data will be send back to your parent div.

Comment: @ Chris Wickham you can add a object for all variables in data like validables:{kmMins:0, kmSecs:0, miMins:0, miSecs:0} , then watch the object itslef by using deep: true 
https://michaelnthiessen.com/how-to-watch-nested-data-vue/ 
the following link contains information for watch types